# How to define models/serializers correctly for Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

We are creating a mobile web application with this stack:

Python
Django, SQLite DB
Django REST
Ionic Cordova
Angular JS

This is a quiz application, in which you answer questions from 4 multiple choices. Questions and answers are stored in the database. With the help of REST framework an endpoint has been created.

With this JSON file our Angular JS controller works asynchronously.
The problem is defining answers in model.py. It involves an array in an array.

We're trying to get this structure with Django REST:

```
[
    {
        "question" : "Java was originally developed at _______________",
        "answer"  : [
        {"id"  : 0, "text" : "Sun Microsystems"},
        {"id"  : 1, "text" : "Intel"},
        {"id"  : 2, "text" : "Hewlett-Packard"},
        {"id"  : 3, "text" : "Oracle"}
        ],
        "correct"  : 0
    },
]
```

And this is what we have:

```
[
    {
        "question": "Java was originally developed at _______________",
        "answer": [
            {
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/answer/1/",
                "answerid": 0,
                "text": "Sun Microsystems"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/answer/2/",
                "answerid": 1,
                "text": "Intel"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/answer/3/",
                "answerid": 2,
                "text": "Hewlett-Packard"
            },
            {
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/answer/4/",
                "answerid": 3,
                "text": "Oracle"
            }
        ],
        "correct": 0
    }
]
```

Here's our models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Answer(models.Model):
    answerid = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
    correct = models.IntegerField()
```

serializer:

```
from quiz.models import Question, Answer
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('answerid', 'text')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question', 'answer', 'correct')
        read_only_fields = ('answer',)
        depth = 1

# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer

class AnswerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer
```

Is it somehow possible to remove the urls in our solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urls come because you inherit `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
```

If you don't want them, use a different base class - perhaps just a [`ModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer).

Comment: Thanks! I used the ModelSerializer and it finally worked.

`class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('text')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question', 'answers', 'correct')
        read_only_fields = ('answers',)
        depth = 1`

I also had to remove the custom ID since the IDs were set automatically

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work.

```
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('answerid', 'text')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

answer = AnswerSerializer(source="answers) 
class Meta:
    model = Question
    fields = ('question', 'answer', 'correct')
    read_only_fields = ('answer',)
    depth = 1
```

You may need to change the `source` to correctly get the answers you need.

The `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` will automatically insert the url field in your response.